# Angular recive Data with Server-sent-events(EventSource) and handle it between 2 controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, server-sent-events

this are my first stepps with Angular.js. I google a lot,but dosen't find the right answer for my problem.

My final application should look like this:
There is no user interaction.You browse to the Site and everything starts.
The page waits for the server,which will sent Server sent events to the Browser,show it in a table and after a while picks the first item out of the table and works with it.

So i thought it would be the best to make 2 controllers and one factory.
The factory connects to the Server and recived updates over Server sent events,put it into an Array.This Array is passed to the first Controller and showed in the table.
The second controller also access the array(ore use a function to return(and remove) the first item) and works with it.

If found a lot stuff about handle data between 2 controllers and update the view,when the data in the factory changes.Also I found some examples about Server sent events.But they are all done in the controller,ore only moved into a factory and than used in a controller.
But I want to make a central point to hold the data and make the connection with the server and update the controller from this central point.Ore is this the wrong approach?

Should I make the connection in the first controller and push the data than into a factory?Ore only work with $rootScope?I'm clueless about the "right" way to handle my problem.

My code so far,is that the factory connects to my server and(as far as I see) closed the connection immediately and never used the callback.When I Access localhost:3000/getStuff with Chrome,i recived the events.At the moment i changed the code to simple see the events in the console:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp',[]);


module.factory('DataService',function(){

var array=[];
var mesg;
var handleCallback = function (msg) {
    mesg = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    console.log(msg);
    console.log("callback");
}

var source = new EventSource('/getStuff');
source.addEventListener('message',handleCallback,false);

return {
    list: function () {
        return array;
    }

}

})


module.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,DataService){
$scope.array = DataService.list;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

We have built a demo application with Angular using SSE. You can browse it on [GitHub](https://github.com/streamdataio/quizz-apispark-demo), and read the [related blog post](http://streamdata.io/blog/live-quiz-googlesheets-apispark-streamdataio-d3js/) to have a little more context information.
Basically, this application uses APISpark, and Google Sheets to build a quizz, the data are retrieved through streamdata.io, which relies on SSE, to send realtime and differential updates to the UI, based D3.JS.

We have made a factory called apiSparkStreamdataioFactory (in app.service.js) to handle the SSE channel (streamdataio.createEventSource method is a wrapper that will gather all required data, and eventSource is created when stremdata.open method is called). When data is received on the SSE channel, we user $rootScope.$apply to apply a callback which is defined in each view, and handles the received data. See code below :

```
 'use strict';

(function () {

  function apiSparkStreamdataioFactory(quizzConfig, $rootScope) {
    return {
      newStreamdata: function (url) {
        var headers = ['Authorization: Basic ' + btoa(quizzConfig.apiSparkLogin + ':' + quizzConfig.apiSparkPassword)];
        var streamdata = streamdataio.createEventSource(url, quizzConfig.streamdataioAppToken, headers);
        var data = [];

        function open() {
          streamdata.open();
          return this;
        }

        function onData(onDataCallback) {
          streamdata.onData(function (snapshot) {
            data = snapshot;

            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
              onDataCallback(data);
            });
          });

          return this;
        }

        function onPatch(onPatchCallback) {
          streamdata.onPatch(function (patches) {
            jsonpatch.apply(data, patches);

            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
              onPatchCallback(data);
            });
          });

          return this;
        }

        function close() {
          streamdata.close();
          return this;
        }

        function onError(onErrorCallback) {
          streamdata.onError(function (error) {
            onErrorCallback(error);
          });

          return this;
        }

        return {
          open: open,
          onData: onData,
          onPatch: onPatch,
          onError: onError,
          close: close
        };
      }
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('QuizzApp')
    .factory('apiSparkStreamdataioFactory', ['quizzConfig', '$rootScope', apiSparkStreamdataioFactory])
  ;


})();
```

Hope this sample will help you find the right solution for your application.